# 'an' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '='

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

I'm getting this error when I try to submit the XML into the web service which is published on a server. When I submit from the debug mode on Visual Studio, it works fine. I'm really stuck with this. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <AuthUser xmlns="http://xxx.bbb.com/">
            <ClientID>xxx</ClientID>
            <Username>xxx</Username>
            <Password>xxx</Password>
    </AuthUser>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <InsertSecure xmlns="http://xxx.bbb.com/">
      <orderXml>
      <![CDATA[
        <Root>
            <County>Dorset</County>
        </Root>
         ]]>
      </orderXml>
    </InsertSecure>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This is the C# code for submitting the XML

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Use this web service to submit new work orders. This needs authentication")]
    [SoapHeader("User", Required = true)]
    public XmlDocument InsertSecure(string orderXml)
    {
        if (User != null) //check whether the credentials are present
        {
            if (User.IsValid()) // check if the user is valid
            {
                try
                {
                    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
                    xdoc.LoadXml(orderXml);

                    return createXML(xdoc);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
            else
            {
                XmlDocument xAuthDeniedDoc = new XmlDocument();

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>");
                sb.Append("<DocumentElement>");
                sb.Append("<Response>Unauthorized Access");
                sb.Append("</Response>");
                sb.Append("</DocumentElement>");
                xAuthDeniedDoc.LoadXml(sb.ToString());
                return xAuthDeniedDoc;
            }
        }

    }
```

Create XML method

```
 private XmlDocument createXML(XmlDocument xdoc)
{
    try
    {
        string directory = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName;

        string filePath = directory + "WebServiceXML\\";
        string dateStimeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss");
        string fileName = "WorksOrderXML-" + dateStimeStamp + ".xml";

        xdoc.Save(filePath + fileName);

        XmlDocument xSucessDoc = new XmlDocument();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>");
        sb.Append("<DocumentElement>");
        sb.Append("<SuccessResponse>Order Received Successfully");
        sb.Append("</SuccessResponse>");
        sb.Append("</DocumentElement>");
        xSucessDoc.LoadXml(sb.ToString());
        return xSucessDoc;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }

}
```

## Error

```
<faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; System.Xml.XmlException: 'an' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '='. Line 1, position 93.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseAttributes()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElement()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadNode(Boolean skipOverWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml(String xml)
   at Stonewater.StonewaterInsertSecure(String orderXml)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</faultstring>
```

Comment: Please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error message into the *body* of your question.

Comment: **I'm getting this error...** "This" error? Please **show** the error!

Comment: Is the `xml` code above the only code involved in producing the error? I am guessing there is `c#` code as well?

Comment: So what exactly  is line 1 in your code?

Comment: @PeterAbolins c# code is  xdoc.LoadXml(orderXml);

Comment: Calling the web service is working fine, If I give incorrect credentials I get the unauthorized access as expected. So it is the submitting of the xml. But it works fine on the debug.

Comment: So... what you are saying is that **orderXml** == `<Root><County>Dorset</County></Root>`, and that is what produces the error?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] that we could copy and paste locally to reproduce the issue.

Comment: My point is that you have only supplied half the story. The error is telling you that there is a problem interpreting the `xml` you passed in, and in particular where there is a string with a value of **an**. That is obviously not included in what you have supplied us to help solve the problem.

Comment: @PeterAbolins yes.This is exactly what I'm trying to submit  orderXml == <Root><County>Dorset</County></Root>. What I don't understand is there there is no "an" in the XML I'm trying to submit.

Comment: Can you log the data you receive in the web service, just before calling the `LoadXml()` method?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis this is the string passed before calling LoadXml   "\n\t  \n\t\t<Root>\n\t\t\t<County>Dorset</County>\n\t\t</Root>\n\t\t \n\t  "

Comment: And after that data was logged, the error occurred?

Comment: I found the issue, the error message was misleading. Actual error was in the file location. when saving the file

Comment: Thanks all for valuable input

Comment: Can you please fix the question, so it is correct, and then post the solution you found as an answer? As it stands, the question, along with this comment thread, will not help anyone understand what happened.

Comment: @PeterAbolins will do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actual error was file location, Instead of the following,

```
string directory = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName;

string filePath = directory + "WebServiceXML\\";
```

I used,

```
string filePath = @"C:\WebServiceXML\";
```

Thanks all. Your input was highly appreciated