# SSISBuild failing to parse a URL file path

Tags: sql-server, git, ssis, msbuild, devops

I am trying to build SSIS packages using the Microsoft DevOps tools as mentioned below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/devops/ssis-devops-standalone?view=sql-server-ver15

The tool SSISBuild.exe works perfectly fine for a local file path. However, when put a https URL (git stash) path, it throws parse errors as follows:

> '>' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '='. Line 14, position 267.

There is not much README/documentation around this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Any thoughts? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this can help; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50344410/an-is-an-unexpected-token-the-expected-token-is

Comment: My problem is with running the SSISBuild.exe provided by Microsoft. I am not parsing any XML directly in C#. Do we know how can we pass a stash "https" path to SSISBuild.exe without any parsing error. I am using the following command.                       .\SSISBuild.exe -p:https://<stash_url>/SSIS.dtproj -o:C:\<output_path>